# Matrix Formatting

Tags: matrix, formatting, format

I have a program that's written as:

```
n=int(input('Enter dimension less than 10: '))
table=[n*[0] for i in range(n)]

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        table[i][j]=1

for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(1,n):
        table[i][j]=table[i-1][j]+table[i][j-1]

format(table[i][j],'3d')
for i in range(n):
    print(table[i])
```

I am trying to format the matrix so that it looks aligned
the formatting I did prior to the printing does not seem to work
Why is this happening?
Or does formatting only work when I do it in a print function?